# Table Valued Functions in EDMX with Entity Framework 5 / Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

If it possible to use table valued functions in an EDMX with Entity Framework 5 RC / Visual Studio 2010?

I cannot see the option in the EDMX designer, I have a feeling that the designer is in .net 4.5? Are my suspicions correct? Or perhaps in Visual Studio 11?

I'm not really in a position to be able to upgrade our project to .net 4.5 yet, is there another way of using table valued functions (perhaps modifying the edmx by hand?).

ADDITIONAL INFO:

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx) on msdn helps confirm the incompatibility:

> Some features are only available when writing an application that
>   targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types,
>   table-valued functions and the performance improvements. If you are
>   targeting .NET 4.0 you still get all the bug fixes and other minor
>   improvements.

However interestingly, [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support.aspx) discuses modifying the EDMX directly to add support for TVF, but it appears to be for a an old beta. The XML intellisense also didn't find the elements discussed in the tutorial, but it might be because it was using a different schema. **Unfortunately I've run out of time to try and apply the tutorial to the new EF5 Release candidate, but I'd be interested in knowing if anyone has had any luck.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately table valued function support is currently dependent on .NET 4.5 and VS 2012.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, I've updated my question with some extra details I've found that gives a hint of a possible workaround, but unfortunately I've not had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96457/Defining-Custom-Functions-in-Entity-Framework) in order to use table-valued functions from EF 4. Basically it includes hand-editing the EDMX file. The downside to that approach is that you need to edit the file manually whenever you update your model.

Comment: And, unfortunately, it's not composable so you always pull down the whole result-set.  Sigh.  4+ years and still missing things from LINQ-to-SQL 1.0